# How can I select item of a tuple within list?

Tags: python

I have this list of numbers in a file log:

```
[(1, 1)]
[(11, 11)]
[(157, 208)]
[(222, 224)]
[(239, 239)]
[(265, 268)]
```

and I want to print the items like a value of variable like this:

```
x = 1
y = 1
```

and then: return to next line

```
x= 11
y = 11
```

return:

```
x=157
y=208
```

It's possible?

My CODE were:

```
 fhand=open('list.log')
    for lines in fhand:
    print lines
    print (lines[1:1])
```

AND

```
import re
fhand=open('list.log')
for line in fhand:
    line=line.split()
    number=map(lambda line: line.split()[0], line)
    print number
```

I've tried with lambda, map, filter...but I dont know what chance in this code. Please Can somebody help me please? Can somebody tell me what to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`, unpack each item accessing the tuple stored inside each list and print using [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('list.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b = literal_eval(line.rstrip())[0]
        print("x = {}\ny = {}".format(a,b))
x = 1
y = 1
x = 11
y = 11
x = 157
y = 208
x = 222
y = 224
x = 239
y = 239
x = 265
y = 268
```

If you want to store a list of all tuples:

```
 tups = [literal_eval(line.rstrip())[0] for line in f]
 print(tups)
 [(1, 1), (11, 11), (157, 208), (222, 224), (239, 239), (265, 268)]
```

[ast.literal_eval](http://ast.literal_eval):

*Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.*

doing it manually you would need to index 2:-2 after stripping the newline, split on `,` and `map` to int:

```
 for line in f:
    a,b =(map(int,line.rstrip()[2:-2].split(",")))
    print("x = {}\ny = {}".format(a,b))
```

Or use str.translate to remove the commas,parens etc..:

```
with open('list.log') as f:
      for line in f:
        a,b = map(int,line.translate(None,"()[],").split())
        print("x = {}\ny = {}".format(a,b))
```

Comment: Why does my code only strip two of the four characters?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi because you are forgetting the newline, `parse = line.strip('()[]\n').split(',')`

Comment: That didn't work either. It actually switches to the other two characters.

Comment: Using `literal_eval()` is a good approach. However the `print(a, b)` is likely going to produce output like `(1, 1)`, `(11, 11)`, etc because from the code in the OP's question, it looks like they're using Python 2. In addition to that they want each pair to produce something like `x = 1` & `y = 1`.

Comment: @martineau, yes, rereading the question the OP does seem to want formatted output so I added `str.format`

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('list.log') as log:
    for line in log:
        parse = line.strip('()[]\n').split(',')
        print 'x = %s' % parse[0]
        print 'y = %s' % parse[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for line in fhand:
    line = line.strip(); # trim off any leading or extra whitespace including newline
    line = line[2:-2]  # trim off the leading [( and trailing )] chars
    parsed_line = line.split(',') # convert to list 
    print('x =',parsed_line[0].strip())
    print('y =',parsed_line[1].strip())
```

Comment: you will have an extra `)` you need to strip the newline before indexing